# How to Calculate Population from A given Set Of Sampels

Tags: statistics, sampling

I have a sample set of data collected using a SRS of books with IDs from 1 to 100. {90,60,6,39,46,26,16} Using this data how can I estimate the max, in this senario I know the max id, but what if I only had the sample and the max id varied? What formula would I use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The UMVU estimator of the maximum of a discrete uniform distribution is given by
$m + \frac{m}{n} - 1$
where $m$ is the sample maximum (and n the sample size).
This might be what you are looking for?